# Manually wirting code for warpAffine in python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I want to implement affine transformation by not using library functions.
I have an image named "transformed" and I want to apply inverse transformation to obtain "img_org" image. Right now, I am using my own basic GetBilinearPixel function to set the intensity value. But, the image is not transforming properly.This is what I came up with. :

This is image("transformed.png"):

[image]

This is image("img_org.png"):

[image]

But My goal is to produce this image:
[image]

You can see the transformation matrix here:

```
pts1 = np.float32( [[693,349] , [605,331] , [445,59]] )
pts2 = np.float32 ( [[1379,895] , [1213,970] ,[684,428]] )
Mat = cv2.getAffineTransform(pts2,pts1)
B=Mat
```

code:

```
img_org=np.zeros(shape=(780,1050))
img_size=np.zeros(shape=(780,1050))

def GetBilinearPixel(imArr, posX, posY):
return imArr[posX][posY]

for i in range(1,img.shape[0]-1):
    for j in range(1,img.shape[1]-1):
        pos=np.array([[i],[j],[1]],np.float32)
        #print pos
        pos=np.matmul(B,pos)
        r=int(pos[0][0])
        c=int(pos[1][0])
        #print r,c
        if(c<=1024 and r<=768 and c>=0 and r>=0):
            img_size[r][c]=img_size[r][c]+1
            img_org[r][c] += GetBilinearPixel(img, i, j)

for i in range(0,img_org.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0,img_org.shape[1]):
        if(img_size[i][j]>0):
            img_org[i][j] = img_org[i][j]/img_size[i][j]
```

Is my logic wrong? I know that i have applied very inefficient algorithm.
Is there any insight that i am missing?
Or can you give me any other algorithm which will work fine.

(Request) . I don't want to use warpAffine function.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to use `warpAffine()`?

Comment: Yes, I am a teaching assistant in my university. I am writing my own library for giving an assignment to students to make them understand the implementation inside the warpAffine function.

Comment: Where did the points come from?

Comment: I think that the matrix is correct. I want "transformed.png" to transform into "original.png" (transformed -> original). The matrix I calculated is from the 1st and 3rd image that i have shared. pts2 represent 1st image and pts1 represent 3rd image.  I can vectorize the image but I think logic will still remain the same.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on an answer, but I think it'll take me a little while. I'm pretty sure your points are wrong though.

Comment: For your information, I have also applied the warpAffine() function. I am able to obtain the correct result, But still, I don't know what is the problem in hardcoded version.

Comment: Yeah I was wrong, your points are fine. I thought they were wrong because the image was getting warped in basically the opposite way. Check your `x,y` and `row,col` ordering to make sure they're correct; the warped image almost looks like it's correct except it's being placed vertically instead of horizontally, that could be the culprit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I vectorized the code and this method works---I can't find the exact issue with your implementation, but maybe this will shed some light (plus the speed is way faster).

The setup to vectorize is to create a linear (homogeneous) array containing every point in the image. We want an array that looks like

```
x0 x1 ... xN   x0 x1 ... xN   .....   x0 x1 ... xN
y0 y0 ... y0   y1 y1 ... y1   .....   yM yM ... yM
 1  1 ...  1    1  1 ...  1   .....    1  1 ...  1
```

So that every point `(xi, yi, 1)` is included. Then transforming is just a single matrix multiplication with your transformation matrix and this array.

To simplify matters (partially because your image naming conventions confused me), I'll say the original starting image is the "destination" or `dst` because we want to transform back to the "source" or `src` image. Bearing that in mind, creating this linear homogenous array could look something like this:

```
dst = cv2.imread('img.jpg', 0)
h, w = dst.shape[:2]
dst_y, dst_x = np.indices((h, w))  # similar to meshgrid/mgrid
dst_lin_homg_pts = np.stack((dst_x.ravel(), dst_y.ravel(), np.ones(dst_y.size)))
```

Then, to transform the points, just create the transformation matrix and multiply. I'll round the transformed pixel locations because I'm using them as an index and not bothering with interpolation:

```
src_pts = np.float32([[693, 349], [605, 331], [445, 59]])
dst_pts = np.float32([[1379, 895], [1213, 970], [684, 428]])
transf = cv2.getAffineTransform(dst_pts, src_pts)
src_lin_pts = np.round(transf.dot(dst_lin_homg_pts)).astype(int)
```

Now this transformation will send some pixels to negative indices, and if we index with those, it'll wrap around the image---probably not what we want to do. Of course in the OpenCV implementation, it just cuts those pixels off completely. But we can just shift all the transformed pixels so that all of the locations are positive and we don't cut off any (you can of course do whatever you want in this regard):

```
min_x, min_y = np.amin(src_lin_pts, axis=1)
src_lin_pts -= np.array([[min_x], [min_y]])
```

Then we'll need to create the source image `src` which the transform maps into. I'll create it with a gray background so we can see the extent of the black from the `dst` image.

```
trans_max_x, trans_max_y = np.amax(src_lin_pts, axis=1)
src = np.ones((trans_max_y+1, trans_max_x+1), dtype=np.uint8)*127
```

Now all we have to do is place some corresponding pixels from the destination image into the source image. Since I didn't cut off any of the pixels and there's the same number of pixels in both linear points array, I can just assign the transformed pixels the color they had in the original image.

```
src[src_lin_pts[1], src_lin_pts[0]] = dst.ravel()
```

Now, of course, this isn't interpolating on the image. But there's no built-ins in OpenCV for interpolation (there is backend C functions for other methods to use but not that you can access in Python AFAIK). But, you have the important parts---where the destination image gets mapped to, and the original image, so you can use any number of libraries to interpolate onto that grid. Or just implement a linear interpolation yourself as it's not too difficult. You'll probably want to un-round the warped pixel locations of course before then.

```
cv2.imshow('src', src)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: Source image]

Edit: Also this same method will work for `warpPerspective` too, although your resulting matrix multiplication will give a three-rowed (homogeneous) vector, and you'll need to divide the first two rows by the third row to set them back into Cartesian world. Other than that, everything else stays the same.

Comment: Thanks very much. I also thought that, when points transform to negative coordinates, they will not map properly. wanted to use loops instead of inbuilt functions. Nevermind.

Comment: Yeah; in the OpenCV implementation, it just leaves those indices out. Also it requires you to put an output shape, which means that it doesn't automatically calculate the extent, either. Due to this, I created a little python module that performs the OpenCV `warp` functions but automatically calculates the destination size and shifts the image to positive values like I did here. You can check that out [here](https://github.com/alkasm/padded-transformations) if it fits in with anything you're doing.

Comment: What if i want to apply interpolation to this technique.?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, you have the original pixel values, and you have the new locations, so you have everything you need to interpolate. You can create a linear interpolation method (basically, all of the pixels between the new mapped points get assigned some combination of their neighbors values), or a nearest neighbor method yourself, which aren't too bad. But if you want better interpolation, you should use another library like `scipy` or something with methods for 2D interpolation.